# Dealing with missing values conducting CFA/SEM via lavaan

Tags: r, na, missing-data, r-lavaan

I'm conducting CFA, and as a first step I've inspected my data. I explored that the percentage of missing values in the data set is exactly 5%. Moreover, the observed indicators are ordered categorical.

So, I'm wondering what strategy of dealing with missing values is better to choose:

1. using WLSMV estimation approach with listwise deletion method;
2. or applying WLSMV estimation approach with pairwise deletion method?

Thanks in advance for your answers and recommendations!

Comment: This question may be better for Cross Validated instead given its more the why of statistical operations of missingness over coding itself.

Comment: Thanks for noting the more suitable part of the Stack Exchange network for my question!

Comment: No problem alyx!